# How do you display fields created via the File Entity settings configuration?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm using the [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module, and it lets me modify the configuration settings, adding a few fields to a file type, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the custom fields I created to show up in the add content screen. Only the Alt text and Title values show up. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields aren't on the add content screen they are on the add file screen (because they are fields on the file entity).

So if you add files via the file/add page you can fill out those fields.

The media module has a feature so that when you upload a file to a node then it pops up the edit form to edit the fields on that file.

So you upload the file then fill out the extra file fields in a 2 step process and then save the node.

Comment: Thanks for your response, rooby, but I'm still unsure it's working as intended. I don't see a separate file/add page, only a file add interface when adding the file via the content add page. That's where I need to see these new fields. 

What I'm looking for is an expansion to the file description field you can enable in the file field type. I need a second field for "short" description, and possibly an external link field. Is this possible via a contributed module?

Comment: It looks like the best solution for managing multiple fields as one entity is http://drupal.org/project/field_collection

This module allows you to create a collection field, then from the module settings page, you can add multiple fields to that new item. Regretfully, it does take two separate screens and steps, but it is at least possible. Another regret is that it's not supported by the feeds module, so migrating data will be a bit more complex than I'd hoped.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the file/add page should be part of the file_entity module (at least it is in 2.x). I find the media module to be a good solution although the fields aren't directly on the content edit page. Field collection doesn't require going to 2 pages. If you use the "embedded" field widget it is all displayed on the parent content form.

Answer (score 2):

I was also looking for that functionality, and found this module does exactly that: [File Entity Inline](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity_inline)

> This module aims to provide the ability to edit File entities inline,
>   as part of another form (such as nodes). This should enable the
>   ability for reusable and site-wide editing of file properties, such as
>   description, alt text, captions, bylines, etc.

Comment: Ah, looks very interesting, I'll have to play with this one. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8 you can archive this with core elements/modules.

1. activate the core module file_entity
2. in your file type settings /admin/structure/file-types/manage/image add the extra fields a user should be able to use
3. in your contenttype (admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENTTYPE/form-display) choose the Widget "Editable file" for your image field

[image: image widget selector]

If you create a new node, you will be able to edit the extra fields of your image in a popup after clicking "Edit"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Structure > Content Types choose another widget for the image field from 'Image' to 'Media selector'. This will provide a better way to input and edit all the fields provided by File Entity.